# Errors while installing angular 2

Tags: npm, angular

each time i try to install angular 2 on my desk I get this error

```
244 error node v4.3.1
245 error npm  v2.14.12
246 error code ENOTFOUND
247 error errno ENOTFOUND
248 error syscall getaddrinfo
249 error network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:80
249 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
249 error network and is related to network connectivity.
249 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
249 error network
249 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
249 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
250 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I found that it's related to a proxy I tried to config it but it not work ?

this is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "typings" : "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.20",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5",
    "typings":"^0.6.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json?`

Comment: do you ping registry.npmjs.org ?

Comment: yes (from the browser)

Answer (score 0):

I set same parameters for npm  in .npmrc file and it's work

registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"strict-ssl=false                 proxy="http://username:passwordproxy:port"https-proxy="https://username:passwordproxy:port"